# extract text between tabs

Tags: regex

I have the tab separated line

```
13723181    2018-04-26 14:57:35 NULL    2   5   put quotes around,this.text 1   2018-04-26 14:57:35 NULL    921011  1499
```

used " \t " as tab-character just to clarify the location of the actual tabs

```
13723181 \t 2018-04-26 14:57:35 \t NULL \t 2 \t 5 \t put quotes around,this.text \t 1 \t 2018-04-26 14:57:35 \t NULL \t 921011 \t 1499
```

I want to be able to rewrite this line into a 'proper' csv-line, that looks like this:

```
13723181,2018-04-26 14:57:35,NULL,2,5,"put quotes around,this.text",1,2018-04-26 14:57:35,NULL,921011,1499
```

I suppose this can be done in two steps:

1. put quotation-marks around text that contains a comma, and is
   surrounded by tabs
2. replace all tabs with commas

step 2 is easy..
I'm struggeling on step 1, how to find a substring containng a comma and that is surrounded by tabs, but does not contain a tab itself.. I feel I'm pretty close with

```
(?<=\t)(.*,.*?)(?=\t)
```

but this matches `2018-04-26 14:57:35   NULL    2   5   put quotes around,this.text`
and not `put quotes around,this.text` i want to use...

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you coke up with the answer <1 minute after posting a question :)

`(?<=\t)([^\t]+,[^\t]+)(?=\t)`

works exactly as i need.